# Почему сайт на Open Server развернулся частично?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-сервер, openserver

Привет друзья! Привет мир!

Мне необходимо развернуть сайт на локальном сервере `Open Server`. Однако при раварачивании сайта он перенёсся не полностью на локалку. Хочу отметить то, что в этом сайте `CMS` самописанная.

Вот мои действия которые я проделал.

1. В файле `.htaccess` поменял ссылки с `sport-concept.ru` на `sport-concept.loc`, для того чтобы не было редайректа и сайт на разварачивался у меня на сервере.
2. `db_sportconcep1.wd1.mysql`- файл БД открыл, и поменял все ссылки с `sport-concept.ru` на `sport-concept.loc`
3. Импортировал БД через `PhpMyAdmin`
4. В файле db.php редактировал следующим образом

   `<?
   $mydbhost = 'sport-concept.loc';
   $mydbname = 'sport-concept';
   $mydblogin = 'root';
   $mydbpassword = '';
   ?>`
5. И вот что у меня собственно получилось
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. А вот что должно было получиться
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, главный вопрос состоим в том, в чем причина? Почему у меня так все получилось ? В чем моя ошибка ????

Comment: причин может быть множество , а последствия могут быть разными .

Comment: обычно в случаях, когда что-то идет не так, то смотрят а) в логи сервера а.a) открывают `error_reporting(1);` и смотрят  б) в консоль браузера .... в случае переноса с одного сервера в на другой смотрят совпадение версий тех технологий, которые используются и библиотех их содержащие...